# Getting alloy element id as a variable

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

In Alloy Titanium, I can access XML elements with their id $.element_id but what if the element_id is a variable in the controller how i can get it.
for example, what i want to do is something like this :

```
var x = 'y';
$.x.open();
```

where x is an id for element in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such case you simply have to reference the view in a different way.

there you go:

```
var x = 'y';
$[x].open();
```

Let me know when this works-out for you.